# How do you contain a Interactive Viewer to a box?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm trying to create an app to control a matrix of LEDs, I want the user to be able to select the color for each box. User can zoom in to be able to select individual boxes.

I seems like Interactive Viewer would work, the issue I'm having is when the user zooms in it fills the screen, is there a way to "clip" the rest of the view to the same size as the original?

Can you contain an interactive view within a box? I don't want the zoomed image to leave said box. I've tried looking to clipping but I'm not sure if it works with interactive viewer

[image: UI of the app]

Comment: Can you explain a bit more on `"clip" the rest of the view to the same size`? Is it that you want to keep the zoom effect and not let it return back to original size originally, or zoom only part of the screen?

Comment: Basically in the first image that's the size i want the interactive view to be and when you zoom in it stays contained inside that area, right now when you zoom it extends beyond that area.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To limit the `InteractiveViewer` boundary, you can put it in a `Column`, put the below panel inside an `Expanded` widget and set the width and height of the inside `Container`.

Working code:

```dart
class SomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SomeScreenState createState() => _SomeScreenState();
}

class _SomeScreenState extends State<SomeScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Column(
        children: [
          Container(
            height: 220,
            child: InteractiveViewer(
              minScale: 1,
              maxScale: 3,
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.cyanAccent,
                padding: EdgeInsets.symmetric(horizontal: 5),
                child: GridView.count(
                  crossAxisCount: 10,
                  crossAxisSpacing: 5,
                  mainAxisSpacing: 5,
                  children: List<Widget>.generate(
                    50,
                    (index) => Container(
                      width: 10,
                      height: 10,
                      color: Colors.red,
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              color: Colors.white,
              height: double.infinity,
              width: double.infinity,
              child: Text("HELLO"),
            ),
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Demo video:

[image]

Comment: That's exactly what I'm looking for, thank you very much @Bach

Comment: This works until you try and put anything inside that bottom container, then it reverts to the same issue before.

Comment: @Matt Just edited my answer, please check

Comment: Thanks again after playing around some, wrapping the interactive view container with ClipRect also did the trick.